# If condition in combineLatest observables

Tags: javascript, angular-2+, rxjs

I have many observables so I use `combineLatest` in RxJS. After get all results I need to check one of value by using if condition. If the condition meets then call another HTTP service so I use another observable. Finally I render the data into UI.

```
const a$ = this.http.get('url_a'); // observable
const b$ = this.http.get('url_b'); // observable
const c$ = this.http.get('url_c'); // observable
const d$ = this.http.get('url_d'); // observable
const e$ = this.http.get('url_e'); // observable
const f$ = this.http.get('url_f'); // observable
combineLatest([a$, b$, c$, d$, e$, f$])
.pipe(
 take(1),
 mergeMap(([ra, rb, rc, rd, re, rf]) => {
    this.resp1 = ra;
    this.resp2 = rb;
    this.resp3 = rc;
    this.resp4 = rd;
    this.resp5 = re;
    this.resp6 = rf;
    // below is the condition, if it meets I call another http 
    if (this.resp3.id < a_constant) {
        this.resp3.step = constant;
        return this.http.put('url_another'); // observable
    }
    // then I use a trick below
    return of(1); // trick observable
 }))
.subscribe(() => {
     this.step = this.resp3.step - 1;
     // other rendering ui work by returning results such as resp1, resp2, etc.
 });
```

The issue is that if `if (this.resp3.id < a_constant)` I want to update something. So the `this.resp3.id` maybe changes. I want this value finally.
I use `return of(1)` the trick. Although it works but it is ugly.

**EDIT:**
Per feedback, I added additional info.
The issue is I want to listen an observable. Usually it is `this.http.put('url_another')` so I can subscribe it. But there is a if condition so this observable is not always created. But I have to subscribe something. Then I use an unrelated observable `of(1)` to listen.

`of(1)` is a fake observable.

Comment: This code looks anonymized / obfuscated, and you haven't done a good job of explaining what it does.

Comment: Please present, at the very least, the entire procedure for review: [Good advice needs context](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @greybeard, I added it. If it still doesn't meeting the requirement; I am okay to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a few questions:

What is the return of(1) trick doing? The combineLatest isn't being stored in a variable and the subscribe takes no parameter, so what is the of(1) doing?

What is the purpose of combining these observables? You don't seem to be doing anything with the result of the combination. Why not just work with the `a$`, `b$`, etc variables instead of copying the result to `this.respx` variables? Then you could use an async pipe in the template to display each of the `a$`, `b$` data.

One a minor thing in the code, you don't need a `take(1)` because each of your Observables only emit once and complete. So the combineLatest will only emit one time.

Also, you could do something like this:

```
const c$ = this.http.get('url_c').pipe(
  map(data => {
    if (this.resp3.id < a_constant) {
        this.resp3.step = constant;
        return this.http.put('url_another');
    }
  }
)
```

Does that help?

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community, and good answer. Not all questions on code review should be answered, this is one of those questions because it doesn't provide enough detail. The question is heading towards being closed because it is missing Code Review Context.